# Implicit solution: Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\sec^2\theta\sec^3r$$

I used the separable equations method and got to the following implicit solution:

$$\sin r\cos^2r+\frac{2\sin^3 r}{3}=\tan\theta+C$$

I was wondering if I can get any further with another method or using any trigonometric identities.

Comment: what method have yo9u got in mind? have you tried WolframAlpha?

Comment: I did, and it got to something else which is equivalent (something involving sin(9x)), but I was not able to see how it got there because I can't access the step by step solution

Comment: Well your problem is $\cos^3r \ dr = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$  equivalent to $\frac{1}{4}(3\cos r + \cos 3r) dr = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$. You can take indefinite integrals of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon iamvegan's comment you can rewrite it as:

$$\int\frac{3\cos r}{4}+\frac{\cos3r}{4}dr=\int\sec^2\theta d\theta$$

which simply integrates to:

$$\frac{3\sin r}{4}+\frac{\sin3r}{12}=\tan\theta+C$$

which is equivalent to your statement.

WolframAlpha can give you $r$ as a function of $\theta$ but it is not nice:

$$r=2(\arctan(x)+n\pi)$$

where $x$ is the 6 possible roots of $(3x^6+9x^4+9x^2+3)(\tan\theta+C)-6x^5-4x^3-6x=0$